# different between using map function and not

Tags: python, list

I'm taking the Intermediate Machine Learning course at Kaggle well it gives us Home data to learn from it. Why do they use map function when they shouldn't, like here :

```
# Get the number of unique entries in each column with categorical data
object_nunique = list(map(lambda col: X_train[col].nunique(), object_cols))
```

but it can be as simple as this :

```
object_nunique1= list(X_train[object_cols].nunique())
```

is there something I miss (which I don't think so because both give the same answer)?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `kaggle` - kindly do not spam irrelevant gags (removed).

Comment: Nothing missed. You'd have to ask whoever created the course/code, but they probably simply overlooked this. That sometimes happens if there are multiple ways to get to the same answer: one may miss the more obvious solution. (I would even have kept the result as a series, so you still have the column-name - count mapping. Even more so, because the next step turns the result into exactly such a dict.)